# WiFi gone after system freeze

Tags: 14.04, wireless, google-chrome, internet

I was browsing the Internet in chrome when my system froze, completely unresponsive. I waited an hour and checked back and it was still frozen, so I had to just power down by holding the power button. Ever since, my WiFi is gone. When I click on the little WiFi icon in the system bar up top, the "Enable Wifi" option is gone, and obviously no WiFi names are present. A proper restart does nothing, and I have no way to get a wired connection established.

Edit: `rfkill list all` outputs nothing. `dmesg | grep iwl` outputs nothing. `lsmod | grep iwl` outputs nothing. `lspci` outputs `3a:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d21 (rev 21)`. And `sudo dpkg --configure -a` does nothing.

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo dpkg --configure -a` ?. Also, if this does not work, try to reinstall the driver. If this dont work, try to replug the WiFi card, but first, remove the battery, then, press the power button for at least 30 seconds. Reconnect your WiFi and then the battery. Finally, tur on your computer.

Comment: No that did not work, and I cannot remove the WiFi card or battery without significant hassle as this is an ultrabook. I can try to reinstall the driver, but no `apt-get` approaches will work since I have no Internet access.

Comment: You can try using your live USB, boot with it, and verify that WiFi is working on the live system. Otherwise, it could be a hardware problem